# Windows system variables not visible for non-admin user

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I have a problem with accessing system variables by regular (non-admin) users.

Let's say I created a system variable `MY_VAR`. When I access it via Python from the admin account, it works fine, but when I'm trying to do that on regular user's account, it cannot see the variable.

I could set it as a user environment variable for the regular user account, but I need this variable to be available for all users (current and future), so it won't work on a long run.

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: System variables applies to all users unless that user overrides it...

Comment: @Anders That's what I thought, but I cannot access these variables when running python on regular user. Maybe a restart is needed?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out a system restart was needed. After that it started to work as expected.